sidebase library nuxt-auth Configuration error
I am trying to use sidebase nuxt auth for my application. But i'm configuration getting error and my app not working (500 error)
I tried CredentialsProvider.default but not working.
Please help..
✔ Nuxt Nitro server built in 366 ms                                                             nitro 18:38:12
ERROR  [nitro] [uncaughtException] CredentialsProvider is not a function
at  (server\api\auth[...].ts:10:1)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:268:25)
at async onImport.tracePromise.proto (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:543:26)
at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:116:5)
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^9.1.1",
    "@primevue/nuxt-module": "^4.2.5",
    "@sidebase/nuxt-auth": "^0.10.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "next-auth": "~4.21.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.14.1592",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "vue": "latest",
    "vue-router": "latest"
  } 

*nuxtconfig file
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-11-01',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/i18n', '@primevue/nuxt-module', '@sidebase/nuxt-auth'],
  auth: {
    globalAppMiddleware:true,
    baseURL: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
    provider: {
      type:"authjs"
    }
  }

server/api/auth/[...].ts file
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

const config = useRuntimeConfig()


export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    secret: config.authSecret,
    providers:[
        CredentialsProvider({
            name:"Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {label:"Email",type:"email",placeholder:"Email"},
                password: {label:"Password",type:"password",placeholder:"Password"}
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                // You need to provide your own logic here that takes the credentials
                // submitted and returns either a object representing a user or value
                // that is false/null if the credentials are invalid.
                // e.g. return { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }
                // You can also use the `req` object to obtain additional parameters
                // (i.e., the request IP address)
                const res = await fetch(config.apiUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                })
                const user = await res.json()
        
                // If no error and we have user data, return it
                if (res.ok && user) {
                return user
                }
                // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
                return null
            }
    })],
    pages: {
        signIn:"/login"
    }
});


What is tsconfig?
